# Remove Cells from D3 Observable When Embedding into Application

Tags: javascript, d3.js, observablehq

Say I am embedding [this](https://observablehq.com/@d3/horizontal-bar-chart) visual from D3 Observable into my own application. We can embed these by downloading the tarball file:

[image]

But this downloads all the cells that are useful for running the notebook online but are no longer needed when showing the visual in an application. How can I remove these cells?

[image]

I can run:

```
$('span').remove()
```

...but there must be a better way.

Comment: You can now generate code to embed certain cells by clicking “Embed cells” in the notebook menu: https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/introduction-to-embedding; @tmcw's advice is elaborated upon here https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/downloading-and-embedding-notebooks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure thing – to just display the `chart` cell, you can change

```
const main = runtime.module(define, Inspector.into(document.body));
```

Which displays all the cells, with

```
const main = runtime.module(define, name => {
  if (name == 'chart') {
    return new Inspector(document.body)
  }
});
```

Which looks just for the cell named 'chart'.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on this answer, this is how you show more than 1 cell based on its title:

In the body of the HTML file (index.html), create the elements (I'm going to use 2):

```html
<p id="title"></p>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

and then within the `<script>` tags you add the following:

```js
function renderNotebook(notebook, cellNames) {
  new Runtime().module(notebook, name => {
    if (cellNames.includes(name)) {
      return new Inspector(document.querySelector(`#${name}`));
    }
  });
}

renderNotebook(define, ["title", "chart"])
```

Note that the cells I want to display are called `title` and `chart`. Hope this helps! Source: https://talk.observablehq.com/t/overcoming-r-is-not-iterable-with-new-runtime-or-another-mistake/2729/7